# In which file is the Ubuntu system path set?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have system path

```
vickey@tb:~/work/sayonara$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.0/bin:/home/vickey/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/vickey/bin:/home/vickey/tunebasket/p2p/
vickey@tb:~/work/sayonara$ cd /usr/local/
```

I want to get rid of the first entry PERMANENTLY . Where is the system path being set ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should first start looking at:

```
/etc/environment
```

If it is not included there, take a look at:

```
/etc/profile
```

The next possible location depends on the shell you are using. All shells also have a default config file located in /etc like /etc/bash.bashrc.

Answer (score 4):

/etc/environment

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables